# Can't embed a TikTok video

Tags: javascript, html, embed, tiktok

I just wanted to embed a TikTok video to my local website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@zacksjerryrig/video/6828268207359413509" data-video-id="6828268207359413509" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@zacksjerryrig" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@zacksjerryrig">@zacksjerryrig</a> <p>Buy a case for your iPad or else... @whatsinside  did the same test, go see how it turned out <a title="ipad" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/ipad">##ipad</a> <a title="teardown" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/teardown">##teardown</a> <a title="jerryrig" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/jerryrig">##jerryrig</a> <a title="jerryrigeverything" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/jerryrigeverything">##jerryrigeverything</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ original sound - Zack" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-6828268206063405830">♬ original sound - Zack</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It won't show the video itself and all the captions lost their styles.

Comment: I tested your code in Google Chrome and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. That's really strange, I've tried that in Microsoft Edge as well as Chrome, in both cases the video disappears. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

TikTok officially provide Embed tag to your website. you can just copy that HTML Tag and past in your code base.

Official documentation
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/Embed

Image below shows how to copy that embed html code.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Somehow it doesn't work. Yeah seems easy to make, but it doesn't work, maybe I'm missing something in my code

Comment: It's working fine on chrome! Which browser you're using?

Comment: I tried Microsoft Edge and Chrome. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is issue with "cross-site" cookie planting attempt by tiktok. If this is issue, you will see it as an "issue" - say in chrome developer console.

If this is indeed an issue then there is another issue to be careful of: need to be careful of European laws which require disclosure of non-essential cookies.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31719063)

Answer (score 0):

please use embed URL.

```
    <blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@zacksjerryrig/video/6828268207359413509" data-video-id="6828268207359413509" style="max-width: 605px; min-width: 325px;">
       <iframe
          name="__tt_embed__v6828268207359413509"
          sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-same-origin"
          src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed/v2/6828268207359413509?lang=en-US&amp;"
          style="width: 100%; height: 707px; display: block; visibility: unset; max-height: 707px;"
       ></iframe>   
   </blockquote>
   <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 based on all embeds on other networks

     ////////////////
           ////////////////////////////////checkeachpost////////////
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function autolink($string)
    {
    // force http: on www.
    $string = str_ireplace( "www.", "http://www.", $string );

// eliminate duplicates after force

$string = str_ireplace( "http://http://www.", "http://www.", $string );

$string = str_ireplace( "https://http://www.", "https://www.", $string );
 $string = str_replace( '&amp;nbsp;', ' ', $string);


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///////////////emoticons///////////////////




$string = str_ireplace(':)', '<img src="emoticons/ico.jpg" title=":)"/>', 
 $string);
    $string = str_ireplace(';)', '<img src="emoticons/ico2.png" title=";)"/>', 
        $string);
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// The Regular Expression filter




$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3} 
(\/\S*)?/";
// Check if there is a url in the text

    $m = preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $match); 

         if ($m) { 
              $links=$match[0]; 
                for ($j=0;$j<$m;$j++) { 



    if(substr($links[$j], 0, 18) == 'https://www.tiktok'||substr($links[$j], 0, 
   17)== 'http://www.tiktok'||substr($links[$j], 0, 17) == 
      'http://www.tiktok'||substr($links[$j], 0, 18) == 'https://www.tiktok'){

           $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" 
             rel="nofollow" 
    target="_blank"></a>',$string).'<br/><iframe title="YouTube video player" 
            align="left"  class="tiktok-embed"  width="auto" height="707" 
                 src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed/'.substr($links[$j], -20).'" 
                     frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe><br/>';


            
            
            
            
            
            
            
}else if(substr($links[$j], 0, 19) == 'https://www.youtube'||substr($links[$j], 0, 18)== 'http://www.youtube'||substr($links[$j], 0, 16) == 'http://www.youtu'||substr($links[$j], 0, 17) == 'https://www.youtu'){

$string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>',$string).'<br/><iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="260" height="175" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.substr($links[$j], -11).'" frameborder="0" 
    allowFullScreen></iframe><br/>';


}
    else if(substr($links[$j], 0, 16) == 'http://www.youtu'||substr($links[$j], 
     0, 18) == 'https://www.youtu'||substr($links[$j], 0, 13) == 
  'https://youtu'||substr($links[$j], 0, 12) == 'http://youtu')
     {

         $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" 
    target="_blank"></a>',$string).'<br/><iframe title="YouTube video player" 
    class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="260" height="175" 
                           
                 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.substr($links[$j], -11).'" 
      frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe><br/>';


     }
    else if(substr($links[$j], 0, 18) == 
          'https://soundcloud'||substr($links[$j], 0, 17) == 
          'http://soundcloud'||substr($links[$j], 0, 21) == 
              'http://www.soundcloud'||substr($links[$j], 0, 22) == 
       'https://www.soundcloud')
       {
            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" 
              rel="nofollow" target="_blank">soundcloud</a>',$string).'<br/> 
                          <iframe width="70%" height="250" scrolling="no" 
                              frameborder="no" 
                               src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/url='.$links[$j].'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true 
             &amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" 
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe><br/>';



   }

else if(substr($links[$j], 0, 21) == 'https://www.reverbnat'||substr($links[$j], 
  0, 20) == 'http://www.reverbnat')
  {
    $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" 
        target="_blank"></a>',$string).'<br/><iframe width="100%" height="200" 
         scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="'.$links[$j].'" 
        style="width:0px;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;"></iframe>';


                                                                                                    




       }  
          else if(substr($links[$j], 0, 8) == 'https://'||substr($links[$j], 0, 
           7) == 'http://')
       {
       $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" 
     target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).'<br/>';



        }else{
          $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" 
       rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string);





     } 

 } 
 } 




           return ($string);
    }





       ?>

               <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```